# $addToSet and return all new items added?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is it possible to `$addToSet` and determine which items were added to the set?

i.e. `$addToSet` tags to a post and return which ones were actually added

Answer (score 0):

Not really, and not with a single statement. The closest you can get is with the [**`findAndModify()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) method, and compare the orginal document form to the fields that you submitted in your [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) statement:

So considering an initial document:

```js
{
    "fields": [ "B", "C" ]
}
```

And then processing this code:

```js
var setInfo = [ "A", "B" ];

var matched = [];

var doc = db.collection.findAndModify(
    { "_id": "myid" },
    {
        "$addToSet": { "fields": { "$each": setInfo } }
    }
);

doc.fields.forEach(function(field) {
    if ( setInfo.indexOf(field) != -1 ) {
        matched.push(field);
    }
}); 

return matched;
```

So that is a basic JavaScript abstraction of the methods and not actually **`nodejs`** general syntax for either the native node driver or the Mongoose syntax, but it does describe the basic premise.

So as long as you are using a "default" implementation method that returns the "original" state of the document before it was modified the you can play "spot the difference" as it were, and as is shown in the code example.

But doing this over general "update" operations is just not possible, as they are designed to possibly affect one or more objects and never return this detail.